# Select n-grams which contain at least one number

Tags: python, nltk

I have a list of n-grams

```
('allo', 'stesso', 'modo', 'dell’italia,', 'che')
('stesso', 'modo', 'dell’italia,', 'che', 'sta')
('modo', 'dell’italia,', 'che', 'sta', 'già')
('dell’italia,', 'che', 'sta', 'già', 'pensando')
('che', 'sta', 'già', 'pensando', 'alla')
('sta', 'già', 'pensando', 'alla', 'riapertura')
('soli', '2.900,', 'contando', 'un', 'crollo')
('2.900,', 'contando', 'un', 'crollo', 'del')
('contando', 'un', 'crollo', 'del', '99.9%')
('un', 'crollo', 'del', '99.9%', 'rispetto')
('che', 'prevede', '12,5', 'miliardi', 'di')
('prevede', '12,5', 'miliardi', 'di', 'dollari')
('12,5', 'miliardi', 'di', 'dollari', 'per')
...
```

created by

```
from nltk import ngrams

n = 5
list_ngrams=[]

for i in my_list:
    grams = ngrams(i.split(), n)

    for gram in grams:
        print(gram)
        list_ngrams.append(gram)
```

I would like to select only the n-grams which contain at least one number, e.g.

```
('soli', '2.900,', 'contando', 'un', 'crollo')
('2.900,', 'contando', 'un', 'crollo', 'del')
('contando', 'un', 'crollo', 'del', '99.9%')
('un', 'crollo', 'del', '99.9%', 'rispetto')
('che', 'prevede', '12,5', 'miliardi', 'di')
('prevede', '12,5', 'miliardi', 'di', 'dollari')
('12,5', 'miliardi', 'di', 'dollari', 'per')
```

Could you please help me to select it?

Comment: Yes, I would consider as a number. Also 9.9$ or £ in case there would be similar cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
l = [('allo', 'stesso', 'modo', 'dell’italia,', 'che'),
     ('stesso', 'modo', 'dell’italia,', 'che', 'sta'),
     ('modo', 'dell’italia,', 'che', 'sta', 'già'),
     ('dell’italia,', 'che', 'sta', 'già', 'pensando'),
     ('che', 'sta', 'già', 'pensando', 'alla'),
     ('sta', 'già', 'pensando', 'alla', 'riapertura'),
     ('soli', '2.900,', 'contando', 'un', 'crollo'),
     ('2.900,', 'contando', 'un', 'crollo', 'del'),
     ('contando', 'un', 'crollo', 'del', '99.9%'),
     ('un', 'crollo', 'del', '99.9%', 'rispetto'),
     ('che', 'prevede', '12,5', 'miliardi', 'di'),
     ('prevede', '12,5', 'miliardi', 'di', 'dollari'),
     ('12,5', 'miliardi', 'di', 'dollari', 'per')]

l2 = [i for i in l if any(any(w.isdigit() for w in s) for s in i)]

print(l2)
```

Output:

```
[('soli', '2.900,', 'contando', 'un', 'crollo'), ('2.900,', 'contando', 'un', 'crollo', 'del'), ('contando', 'un', 'crollo', 'del', '99.9%'), ('un', 'crollo', 'del', '99.9%', 'rispetto'), ('che', 'prevede', '12,5', 'miliardi', 'di'), ('prevede', '12,5', 'miliardi', 'di', 'dollari'), ('12,5', 'miliardi', 'di', 'dollari', 'per')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will select all tuples that contain any element with some characters in the range `0 - 9`. Modify the regex if it needs to be more restrictive:

```py
import re

def filter_ngrams(ngrams):
    return [ngram for ngram in ngrams
            if any(re.match('\d', word) for word in ngram)]

print(filter_ngrams(ngrams))
```

Output:

```py
[('soli', '2.900,', 'contando', 'un', 'crollo'), ('2.900,', 'contando', 'un', 'crollo', 'del'), ('contando', 'un', 'crollo', 'del', '99.9%'), ('un', 'crollo', 'del', '99.9%', 'rispetto'), ('che', 'prevede', '12,5', 'miliardi', 'di'), ('prevede', '12,5', 'miliardi', 'di', 'dollari'), ('12,5', 'miliardi', 'di', 'dollari', 'per')]
```